# using workflow tool to structure shell scripts

Tags: python, shell, workflow

I have a bunch of shell scripts and  I want to sequence them. I can write a master shell script. But I'm not so good at shell scripting.
I heard about drake as a job control flow tool. I want to see if it can used for creating/running the shell scripts in an integrated fashion

Example:

```
nohup run shell_script_1.ksh
Once this is successfully complete run next else exit with error code 1
nohup run shell_script_2.ksh &
nohup run shell_script_3.ksh
Once both the scripts run successfully, move to next else exit with error code 2
nohup ksh shell_script_4.ksh&
nohup ksh shell_script_5.ksh&
nohup ksh shell_script_6.ksh&
Once the above 3 scripts complete, move to next else exit with error code3
finally execute
nohup ksh shell_script_4.ksh
```

Alternatively, If I  arrange thethe rules for running these scripts in a YAML file, is there any master shell script generator that I can use?

Thanks
Pari

Comment: This question is unclear - do you really mean to ask "Can Drake be used to run shell scripts in an integrated fashion?" I'm just guessing, though, because your first paragraph contains only statements, no question. The actual question is off-topic as it's asking for an off-site resource. Instead of wasting rep on a bounty, I'd rather rework it into something more on-topic, to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this. Save this as run_scripts.ksh and then run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
trap '' HUP
trap 'echo EXITING DUE TO SIGNAL ; exit 15' INT TERM

${SHELL-ksh} shell_script_1.ksh || exit 1

${SHELL-ksh} shell_script_2.ksh &
${SHELL-ksh} shell_script_3.ksh || exit 2
wait || exit 2

${SHELL-ksh} shell_script_4.ksh &
${SHELL-ksh} shell_script_5.ksh &
${SHELL-ksh} shell_script_6.ksh &

for x in 4 5 6
do
    wait || exit 3
done

${SHELL-ksh} shell_script_4.ksh     #not 7?
exit $?
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you. Can you help me understand 1.) what trap does? why we are using ${SHELL-ksh} at the start of every command? Is it same as  nohup ksh? 2.)  When we use for x in 4 5 6, if at least one of them fails, will it return exit3 code? 3.) can I add || mailx -s command as well to the exit code?

Comment: The "trap" sets/ignores a signal handler. Doing that for SIGHUP allows you to avoid using nohup. The ${SHELL-ksh} means to use the value of the environment variable $SHELL if set, and if not, defaults to "ksh".  For 4 5 6, the "wait || exit 3" should (but haven't tested it) cause it to exit with status 3 if any of the jobs exit non-zero.  You can change any of the "xxx || exit" to "if ! xxx ; then mailx -s "Job failed" you@example.org" ; exit ; fi".